# Can't unlink file in Codeigniter With File morethan 10 file

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function delete($id){

    $get_img  = $this->db->select('pic1, pic2,pic3,pic4,pic5, pic6,pic7, pic8, pic9, pic10, pic11, pic12')->where('id',$id)->get('napi')->row_array();
    //remove all images
    if($get_img){
        $img = array('pic1','pic2','pic3','pic4', 'pic5', 'pic6', 'pic7', 'pic8', 'pic9', 'pic10', 'pic11', 'pic12');
        foreach($img as $im){
            if($get_img[$im]){
                unlink('assets/pdf/data_napi/'.$get_img[$im]);
            }
        }
    }        
    return $this->db->delete('napi',array('id'=>$id));
}
```

When i try this code, worked but not all erased, please help me

Comment: *erased*? from database or from file system?. either the records are not being removed from database or just one image is get deleted from the folder?

Comment: from table, and also from system, when run my function, not at all deleted, if i have 12 file, when i run my function, just 9 deleted

Answer (score 0):

may be path is the issue.try getting the `document root` then construct the path and using the path `unlink` the files.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/pdf/data_napi/';
f($get_img){
        $img = array('pic1','pic2','pic3','pic4', 'pic5', 'pic6', 'pic7', 'pic8', 'pic9', 'pic10', 'pic11', 'pic12');
        foreach($img as $im){

    if($get_img[$im]){
                unlink($path.$get_img[$im]);
            }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not work, if i change this function only the remaining 1 file not clear, if when upload 1 file, file can be delete but if upload more than 12 file, file can not be removed all

Answer (score 0):

well, in my view, if 9 get deleted, it should delete all. You can do some logging to view which file is being deleted.

So

```
public function delete($id){
    $get_img  = $this->db->select('pic1, pic2,pic3,pic4,pic5, pic6,pic7, pic8, pic9, pic10, pic11, pic12')->where('id',$id)->get('napi')->row_array();
    //remove all images
    if($get_img){
        $img = array('pic1','pic2','pic3','pic4', 'pic5', 'pic6', 'pic7', 'pic8', 'pic9', 'pic10', 'pic11', 'pic12');
        foreach($img as $im){
            if($get_img[$im]){
                unlink('assets/pdf/data_napi/'.$get_img[$im]);
                echo '<p>assets/pdf/data_napi/'.$get_img[$im].'</p>'; // to display image that is deleted.
                $this->db->delete('napi',array('id'=>$id));//delete from db.
            }
        }
    }        
    //return $this->db->delete('napi',array('id'=>$id));
    /* as above line returns the control to it's master after deleting one record only.
       so you need to put this line inside loop*/
}
```

Comment: Hello, when i try your code, just the last file deleted but fisrt file not delete, [link](assets/pdf/data_napi/pic12_21_September_2015_imediabiz.pdf)

Comment: Count File 12 but when delete function just 9 delete, not at all.

Comment: you're saying that it displays 12, but deletes only 9?

Comment: Oww im sorry when i chek the record not inserted to the table, just inserted 9 file,